# Lie group (topological group) action on differentiable stack (topological stack)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groupoids, differentiable-stacks

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathcal{D}$ be a differentiable stack (I am also ok to start with a topological group and topological stack).

I have seen someone mentioning somewhere that the notion of group action on stacks appeared first in [Group Actions on Stacks and Applications](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/matthieu.romagny/articles/group_actions.pdf) by M. Romagny. The below definition of group action on a differentiable stack is from  [Group actions on stacks and applications to equivariant string topology for stacks](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Eginot/papers/Equivariant.pdf) by Gregory Ginot and Behrang Noohi.

A Lie group action on a differentiable stack is given by a morphism stacks $\alpha: G\times \mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ satisfying some conditions. Though they did not specify, I am believe that by $G$ they mean the stack $[*/G]$, so an action of a Lie group $G$ on a differentiable stack $\mathcal{D}$ is a morphism of stacks $\alpha: [*/G]\times \mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ satisfying some conditions (correct me if I am wrong).

Questions :

1. Is there any notion of Lie group $G$ action on a Lie groupoid $[\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0]$? Would a pair of maps $(G\times \mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_1, G\times \mathcal{G}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0)$  giving an action of Lie group on the manifolds $\mathcal{G}_1,\mathcal{G}_0$ compatible with source, target etc maps of Lie groupoid, a good notion of Lie group action on a manifold?
2. Is the notion of Lie group action on a differentiable stack mentioned above deduced/inspired from some notion of Lie group action on a Lie groupoid, in the sense that this notion of Lie group action on Lie groupoid is Moria invariant giving an action of Lie group on a differentiable stack?
3. Is this definition of Lie group action on a differentiable stack directly/indirectly related to the notion of action of a group object on an object of a category as mentioned in Definition $2.15$ of [Notes on Grothendieck topologies, fibered categories
   and descent theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412512.pdf#page22)?

Comment: Thanks @YCor for the edit :)

Comment: I am not sure that $[*/G]$ is the correct object to consider. If you want to recover the action of a group on a manifold in the case that $\mathcal D$ is just a manifold, you really need $G$ to be a Lie group, that is a manifold with extra structure maps (like $G\times G\to G$). I don't think $[*/G]$ would do the job.

Comment: @SebastianGoette That seem to be correct.. :) :) Thank you.. How should I interpret the map $G\times \mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ as?

Comment: I was hoping to see a good answer to your question by somebody else ...

Comment: @SebastianGoette Oh. Please let me know if you have any favorite reference for this set up?

Comment: I think that the $G$-action on $\mathcal D$ should be captured by a map $[\mathcal D/G]\to[*/G]$, not the one that you wrote.

Comment: @Z.M can you please explain in some more words what you mean..

Comment: $G$-torsors on $X$ 1-1 correspond to maps $X\to[*/G]$ via pulling back the "universal $G$-bundle" $*\to[*/G]$, and the pair of $Y$ along with a $G$-action 1-1 corresponds to the pair of $X$ along with a $G$-torsor on $X$ in the following way: $Y=[X/G]$ and $X$ defines a $G$-torsor on $Y$; and a $G$-torsor on $Y$ defines a $G$-bundle $X\to Y$ and thus $X$ carries a $G$-action. Thia holds in any topos, and in particular, in the topos of differential manifolds.

Comment: @Z.M at the level of smooth manifolds, it is clear.. the question was how to understand this at the level of differentiable stack... For a differentiable stack D, a Lie group G, how to think about action of G on D.. one way is to see G as a differentiable stack BG and consider a morphism of stacks $BG\times D\rightarrow D$ (along with some other data)... Do you have any suggestions regarding this idea..

Comment: As I said, it should be $G\times D\to D$ (with data of coherent homotopy), not $BG$ ($G$ is the underlying manifold). A general formalism is given in Lurie's Higher Algebra §4.2 (where we see $D$ as a left $G$-module in the Cartesian monoidal structure).